# retrive data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm  new to android developing.  I tried retrieving data from firebase. which worked . but I'm unable to filter unique identifier from database results .

```
   FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myref = database.getReference("user_foods");
        myref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("foods",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

results  are like

> XsgGhY7qUY5Qa3t8 = {food = apple} , ..... etc

I want to remove that unique identifier & just display results as

> Apple , Mango ...etc

thank you

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#child-events

Comment: cant use getValue().get() method

Comment: As Frank suggested using child event listener did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the answer. If anyone has same issue use   "child event listener "

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myref = database.getReference("user_foods");
    myref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.d("foods",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myref = database.getReference("user_foods");
        myref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d('foods',dataSnapshot.child('food').getValue().toString());
              }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

adding child() to your reference you can access an specific key in your tree. But as Frank suggests try using a POJO class to retrieve all your data from Firebase

edited: sorry i forgot you had many children, you need to make  for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {//code} when your have many children in your node

Comment: If I use dataSnapshot.child("food").getValue().toString()    it throws  "java.lang.NullPointerException"   If I use  dataSnapshot.child('food').getValue().toString() it throws " too many characters in character literal " error

Comment: yes, sorry forgo you had foods{ 1:apple, 2:mango} i updated the answer