# Push data into Firebase from php

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to push some data into my Firebase database via my server script.
I'm using Firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data#fan-out and I know that I need to paste this code:

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase.js"></script> <script>   
    // Initialize Firebase 
  var config = {
            apiKey: "my_apiKey",
            authDomain: "my_authDomain",
            databaseURL: "my_databaseURL",
            storageBucket: "my_storageBucket",   };   firebase.initializeApp(config); 
     </script>
```

Could someone help me where can I put this in my server?

Below, I've created index.html to push some data:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Insert into Firebase</title>
        <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action='insert_into_firebase.php' method='post' id='myform' >
    <p>
    <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='name' id='name' />
    </p>

    <p>
    <input type='text' name='message' placeholder='message' id='message' />
    </p>

    <button id='insert'>Insert</button>

    <p id='result'></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that I need some .php script like "insert_into_firebase.php". 
I have two values(name, text) to insert into my database in Firebase.

I'd like to noted that I'm learning from this tutorial about Android Chat Application https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yt75ZIGdJ4Y&t=791s and I can insert this data(name, text) via android app and read it, but I would like to paste it via my server script.

Comment: you can use javscript codes (read through firebase docs) , or some other way like node.js or angular.js or laravel  to do so. i think simple javascript code snippet will good for you

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup   and then https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Comment: Check your DB connection if its without exception then it should work.

Comment: @Anant I've downloaded and installed this in my computer. But using website I can set more values to insert to firebase.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487073/retrive-data-from-firebase?rq=1#answer-37490344

This may help you.

Comment: @PrasadShinde Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I just need to connect my website script with Firebase to insert data into database in Firebase :)

Comment: Nothing in your current code interacts with the Firebase Database yet. The links that Anant gave are your best starting point, in addition to our [Codelab for web developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). Thanks for watching my Droidcon SF talk btw. ;-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for your support. I read everything again with AngularJS too.